# Excel Cell format wont save

Tags: excel, format

I have a data sheet of an imported IP address table. Sometimes in de IP column he shows
192.168.18.31 but when you open the cell it actually is 1921681831. When i try to change it, by typing '.' between it, it still stays 1921681831. I've tried to check the cell format but everything seems normal.

Anyone an idea how to overcome it, and how to change it? is there a way some automaticly change all the wrong cells. (because i have a data sheet of more than 600 rows)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that Excel treats the value you entered as a normal number, i.e. `1921681831` to which it applies default formatting - which is to add a thousands separator after every 3 digits.

What you need to do instead is to tell Excel to treat the cell as **text**! To so, either start the cell with `'`, i.e. `'192.168.18.31`, or format the cell as Text (in the *Format Cell* dialog in the *Number* tab).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, thats what i did. Only im going to have some problems when my fucntion checks the ip ranges between 172.16 and 172.31, not sure if my function will read the numbers

Comment: you can retrieve the number with a combination of `MID`, `RIGHT` and `VALUE